# Devexpress (v21.2): Could not find assembly Npgsql (during using 'DevExpress ORM Data Model Wizard')

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, xpo

The database is Postgresql and I wanted to use `DevExpress ORM Data Model Wizard` `v21.2`.
I got this error during the process:

> Could not find assembly 'Npgsql'.

I have installed [Npgsql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/) already in my project module.

How can I fix it?

[image: connection failed - DataModel v21.2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded and installed `npgsql.msi` from this link:
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases/download/v4.1.8/Npgsql.msi

for more information:
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/installation.html